# Page numbers restart for preliminary pages

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I have just started typesetting my PhD thesis. I am using the `book` class. I have a parent file where I define style, chapter header styling, page numbering, etc., and I include every chapter using `\include{}`. When compiled I have one single PDF file. However, I have a problem with page numbering on preliminary pages such as Abstract, List of Contents, List of Figures, etc. Page numbers *restart* on every preliminary page. Here is how my TeX file looks like

```
%Page number formatting for preliminary pages.
\fancypagestyle{preliminary}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{preliminary}}}

%Page number formatting for main matter.
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{mainmatter}}

\onehalfspacing

\newenvironment{abstract}{\chapter*{Abstract}}{}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{preliminary}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter

\pagestyle{mainmatter}
\include{chapter1}

\end{document}
```

Am I doing something wrong? I have a suspicion that pre-defined page number formatting at the very beginning is causing this but I am not sure. What do you guys think?

Comment: `\pagenumbering` restarts the page counter at 1, so this is actually reset at page shipout, with every page. So, remove `\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` from the page styles, and include them directly in your document at the appropriate location.

Comment: Thank you @Werner. It worked like a charm. Probably the fastest reply and solution at the same time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define the two page styles `preliminary` and `mainmatter` to be the same, except for the numbering (`roman` in the former, `arabic` in the latter). So, for now, the following setup is what you're after:

```
\documentclass{book}

%... Preamble stuff

% Page style for preliminary pages.
\fancypagestyle{preliminary}{
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% Footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
}

% Page style for main matter.
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% Footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
}

%...

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{preliminary}\pagenumbering{roman}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{preliminary}}% Correct plain page style

%... Preliminary stuff

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{mainmatter}\pagenumbering{arabic}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{mainmatter}}% Correct plain page style

%... Mainmatter stuff

\end{document}
```

Another common way of copying a page style into another is to use

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@preliminary% Copy preliminary page style into plain
\makeatother
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you. Though, I think, you forgot to add `\pagestyle{}` in `\fancypagestyle{}{}`.